# Using a 3rd party module in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs

How can I use this AngularJS module within my application?  https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-credit-cards

I placed the four files in the `/src` directory into a directory on my server.  So it's set up like this:

```
/src
    cvc.js
    expiration.js
    module.js
    number.js
```

Then, in my HTML I have the following:

```
<script src="http://example.com/content/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/content/js/angular-credit-cards/module.js"></script>
```

In my main javascript file, I declare my module with the `credit-cards` dependancy:

```
var checkout = angular.module('checkout', ['credit-cards']);
```

Now, when my page loads, I receive an error that:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I believe this makes sense because as far as I know, `require()` is not a valid command in Javascript. Is this module intended to be used by an AngularJS app? Or is it strictly a NodeJS app? Can it be used in a browser? I feel like I am missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that library requires [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to work correctly.

You can also use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) as part of a build step if you don't want to have `RequireJS` in your app.

Comment: Is there some easy way to just view the source files of the library without installing other tools?

Comment: @flyingL123 Sure you can see it in the [src directory](https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-credit-cards/tree/master/src). However it looks like everything is exporting it's module using `module.exports` so you would need to modify the src files to use the standard angular module definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Each tag contains a UMD build that you can use without any type of build tool, for example:

https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-credit-cards/blob/v2.2.1/release/angular-credit-cards.js

The library does not use RequireJS as the previous answer mentions. Browserify and RequireJS both use a `require` function but are completely different.